# Oracle Equals-Plus Operator (Join On t1.col1 =+ t2.col2)

Tags: sql, join, syntax, oracle11g, operators

I know there are tons of similar questions already, but they don't quite meet my needs. I'm aware that (+) is an Oracle-only join operator used in WHERE clauses, and the the orientation dictates LEFT or RIGHT. However, I'm not entirely sure if my situation matches because the syntax looks different from everything I've found so far. I'm confused because the =+ is in the ON clause instead of the WHERE clause, and it isn't in the same position as examples I've seen. Is this equivalent to (+)? Is it something else entirely? Is it redundant? I don't know what it's doing. I'm just not sure how to deal with this operator in my attempts to simplify this query. Hoping someone can help me out here.

Here's a horrible rendition of the monster I've inherited. This excerpt is then followed by UNION ALL and almost the exact same code block, with some minor differences on a few lines. I'm just tackling the top right now, trying to simplify everything while maintaining the same results. (Yes, it actually runs!) Let me know if I need to clarify. I used the direct code where the meaningful content is.

```
SELECT
  tons,
  of,
  insane,
  fields,
  from,
  way,
  too,
  many,
  different,
  tables
FROM
  seriously,
  these,
  tables,
  are,
  nuts,
  and,
  someone,
  decided,
  to
  LEFT JOIN ( --Two nested subqueries.
    SELECT
      R.SKN_NO
      ,R.REGION_NO
      ,R.REGION_PRICE_FLAG
      ,R.TICKET_RETAIL_DOL
      ,R.CLEARANCE
    FROM(
      SELECT
        P.SKN_NO
        ,P.REGION_NO
        ,P.TICKET_RETAIL_DOL
        ,RI2.REGION_PRICE_FLAG
        ,CASE P.PRICE_TYPE_CODE
          WHEN 'R' THEN 'Y'
          ELSE 'N'
        END CLEARANCE
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY P.SKN_NO, P.REGION_NO
                            ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC) DR
      FROM
        RF_ITEM_PRICING P
        ,RF_ITEM RI2
        ,RF_SYS_PARMS RFID
        ,RF_MERCHANT_ORG MO2
        ,V_HB_STOCK_STATUS HSS2
        ,RF_STORE RS2
      WHERE
        RI2.SKN_NO = P.SKN_NO
        AND RFID.PARM_KEY = 'RFID'
        AND MO2.ORG_NO = 100
        AND MO2.DMM_NO = TO_NUMBER(RFID.MIN_VAL)
        AND RI2.DEPT_NO = MO2.DEPT_NO
        AND RI2.SKN_NO = HSS2.SKN_NO
        AND RS2.STORE_NO_4_DIGIT = HSS2.STORE_NO_4_DIGIT
        AND RI2.REGION_PRICE_FLAG = 'Y'
        AND P.REGION_NO = RS2.STORE_NO
        AND P.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= SYSDATE
      ) R
    WHERE R.DR=1
    ) RFPRICE
    --The two lines below are where the LEFT JOIN finally ends. Note the =+ here.
    ON HSS.SKN_NO =+ RFPRICE.SKN_NO
    AND RFPRICE.REGION_NO = HSS.STORE_NO
WHERE 
  --There are a ton of conditions here 
  --that link all those crazy tables together
  --with the exception of the LEFT JOIN one (alias RFPRICE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Oracle does not have an `=+` operator ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/fusionapps.1111/e20835/appsql.htm#i1033699) is an example of a reference).  It does, however, have an `=` and a unary `+`.  So, I think this would parse as:

```
HSS.SKN_NO = (+ RFPRICE.SKN_NO)
```

This, in turn, would be the same as:

```
HSS.SKN_NO = RFPRICE.SKN_NO
```

The unary `+` operator doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I searched some old Oracle docs as well, and could not find any reference to "=+".  I'm pretty sure it's parsed as in your first example.  I'm also pretty sure that it's NOT parsed as `abs(expn)` though.  Doing some trivial tests, the "=+" just seemed to give the same results as simply a "=".

Comment: Yes, in Oracle, `=+` is nothing more than equal sign followed by unary `+` operator. No, `(+ col_name)` is not the same as `abs(col_name)` - it won't make a numeric value positive if it's negative.

Comment: @Gordon, well that would explain why I can't find any info on it... It's not supposed to be doing any math, even though the data types are numbers. SKN stands for Stock Keeping Number. It's ensuring that it's the same item.

Comment: @MeganHester Yes to both of your questions.

Comment: Thank you. I will remove the `+`. I would upvote, but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score -1):

If the "+" was on the other side of that statement i would say it is a right outer join condition. never have seen it there, though. If you move it to the right of the statement, does it still run? if so its a right outer join to HSS.

I would find out what the program is supposed to do and rewrite it using CTE since it looks like it is doing a ranking based on SKN_NO.

Good luck!

Comment: If I put it on the left side, `+=`, it tells me "Missing Expression." I picked a couple tables outside of this query and compared the counts of a few variations of the join. At this point, I'm inclined to believe it is a simple `=` followed by the unary operator `+` and ignored, as Seeds and Nicholas have said.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the refs I looked at either only say the unary plus is identity or it is "recognized and ignored." I only found one ref (for 9i lite) that indicated it would change the sign positive. Unary plus doesn't do anything on my system. (9.2.0.6.0)

Comment: Do people typically do (anonymous) drive by hating on posts for no reason, or was there some problem worthy of a -1 in my answer? It would have been nice to have a rep higher than one a few times in the past months, and I apparently don't "get" something.